# How to remove file with mv command?

Tags: files, solaris, rm, mv

I started to study  Solaris in my university. Teacher told me to remove a file with `mv` command.
I tried to move a file to /dev/null. But that did not work.

How can I remove file with `mv` command?

Comment: Are you sure your teacher isn't joking, or just mixed up `mv` and `rm`? Moving a file to `/dev/null` can only damage `/dev/null`, it won't delete the file.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith Teacher isn't joking. He said that it's very easy. I don't know, may be he means to use not only `mv` command

Comment: Must be the most stupid exercise ever given by a teacher. Please ask him what he's smoking. Must be doggone good stuff.

Comment: The question is not so bad, it did make some people think and try something which may have been the intention. Anyway, do we answer other people's homework here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
mv other-file file-to-be-deleted
mv file-to-be-deleted other-file
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a (dumb) way to remove your file using `mv`:

```
mv file /tmp
init 6
```

Of course, `rm file` is significantly faster, more efficient and reliable, and less intrusive.

Answer (score 2):

`rm` unlinks your file, and it'll be really hard to get it back.

Perhaps your teacher means something like:

```
mv myfile  ~/.trash
```

(After first having done a `mkdir ~/.trash` of course )

This does a “move to trash” like you see on Windows and OSX (and some linux desktops), instead of unlinking the file.

Later, you can then `cd ~/.trash` and find your file.

Answer (score 1):

Something is removed if it is no longer there where it used to be, that doesn't necessarily imply that it no longer exists or is inaccessible via other means.
Both when using computers and in real life we often remove things by first **moving** them to the trash, from where it still can be retrieved.

Literally a simple

```
 mv filename ../some_other_directory_next_to_the_one_you_re_in/filename
```

already removes the file (from your current directory).

If you need to remove the file **from your computer** using `mv` you can, if networked, use `mv` to move the file to a different computer and assign it a new name (`mv filename /mountpoint/otherfilename` gives you a different file `otherfilename` on the remote system which happens to have the same content as your original `filename`)